# Single statement containing if statement and for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, list-comprehension

I was reading `pathlib` module; and found this:

```
[x for x in p.iterdir() if x.is_dir()]
```

where p is `Path` object, and above line lists all sub directories under that directory.

I want to know what that above complex statement is trying to say,
how both for loop and if statement are combined together
and how can i make such statements by myself.

I am also wondering why that is wrapped in `[]`.

Helps would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Writing:

```
lst = [x for x in p.iterdir() if x.is_dir()]
```

has the same effect of:

```
lst = []
for x in p.iterdir():
    if x.is_dir():
        lst.append(x)
```

and it is called a [list comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk).

Comment: Thanks, helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

That is a python [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).